# webgl texture image source updating

Tags: javascript, html, image, webgl, reloading

I make a small project in webgl, I have a texture drawn on a cube, for the moment no problem :)

But the fact is, that the image is periodly updated keeping the same name.
And what I'd like to do, it's to update the texture when the image update without updating the html page.

I have tried different solution as the SetInterval or the meta which doesn't save the cache... but it doesn't work for the moment.

What I just want is a simple function who force the "re-load" of the image in .jpg periodically. Can you help me ??

Thanks a lot for you future answers ! Have Fun !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a textured cube you just call `gl.texImage2D` with the new image to update the texture

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureToUpdate);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, newImage);
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but the fact is Thatcher the pic keep the same name, so the browser act like if the pic is in the cache and so doesn't want to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to give you an exact solution to your problem.

```
            drawingContext.bindTexture(drawingContext.TEXTURE_2D, webGLTexture);

            drawingContext.texImage2D(drawingContext.TEXTURE_2D,
                                        0,
                                        drawingContext.RGBA,
                                        width,
                                        height,
                                        0,
                                        drawingContext.RGBA,
                                        drawingContext.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                        newData);

            drawingContext.activeTexture(drawingContext.TEXTURE0);
            drawingContext.uniform1i(webGLUTextureLoc, 0);

            // This will most likely be different for you.
            drawingContext.drawArrays(drawingContext.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```